# I need to write an Apache rewrite rule

Tags: apache

Please let me know how to write a single Apache rewrite rule for the following requirement:

Request for /en-us/anything.html should go to   /content/company/us/en/anything.html

Request for /en-ca/anything.html should go to   /content/company/ca/en/anything.html

Request for /fr-ca/anything.html should go to   /content/company/ca/fr/anything.html

Here anything.html could really be anything sometimes abc, def or any other string. I need a single rule to achieve all of the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule    /^(\w{2})\-(\w{2})/(.+)$    /content/company/$1/$2/$3    [L]
```